# Insert date in table using json_populate_recordset

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying insert data in table using this query

```
INSERT INTO table (
url,
v_count,
v_date)
SELECT
url,
v_count,
v_date FROM json_populate_recorset(null::record,
'[{"url_site":"test.com","visit_count":1,"visit_date":"2022-08-31"},
{"url_site":"dev.com","visit_count":2,"visit_date":"2022-08-31"}]'::json) 
AS ("url" varchar(700), "v_count" integer, "v_date" date)
```

And I'm getting this error:
null value in column "v_date" of relation table violates not null constraint

Since my json could be hundreds of entries at some times,
how should I send the date in my json ?
There is another (efficient) way to insert this data in the table ?

Edit: in postico 1.5.20 my example above works as long as I have the json key named the same as the table columns, how can I reference differents names in my json keys?

Comment: `json_populate_recordset` with `record` as the type looks like a bad idea, since it'll basically ignore the property names

Comment: If I use the name of the table, the "as" part is not necessary, thanks. With my original example how can I reference my json keys in my select?

Comment: I'd recommend to just use `json_array_elements(…)`, then `el->>'url_site'`, `(el->> 'visit_count')::int`, `(el->>'visit_date')::date`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `v_date` can resolve to `null`, you'll need to either skip them or provide a value when `null` appears.

To skip the null values, you may want to add a `WHERE v_date NOTNULL` clause to your `SELECT` statement.

Otherwise, you can use `COALESCE()` to assign a value when `v_date` is null.  For example `... SELECT url, v_count, COALESCE(v_date,now()) FROM json_populate_recordset...`